# add image as tooltip for rectangle on canvas

Tags: html, kineticjs

I have a grid and I'm looking to basically add a tooltip Image for each rectangle in the grid. Basically, first I need to be able to add an image to the canvas on the rectangle mouse over event. Eventually each rectangle would have it's own image so I need to keep track of the rectangles...do I add them to an array?

Here is my fiddle for what I've got so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/marseilles84/7ZzTh/1/

Here is a sample image source to use:
'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg';

```
<div id="container"></div>​

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 1000,
  height: 500
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();


for  (var i=0; i<7; i++)
{
    for(c=0; c<18; c++)
    {
              var colorPentagon = new Kinetic.Rect({
              x: (45*c),
              y: 45*i,
              width:40,
              height:40,
              fill: 'red',
              stroke: 'black',
              strokeWidth: 4,
              draggable: true
            });

            colorPentagon.on('mouseover touchstart', function() {
                      //code here
                    });

            layer.add(colorPentagon);    
    }
}

stage.add(layer);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7ZzTh/2/

This is probably more of what you're looking for.

```
        colorPentagon.on('mouseover touchstart', function() {
                 var userPos = stage.getUserPosition();
                 yoda.setPosition(userPos.x,userPos.y);
                 layer.add(yoda);
                  layer.draw();
         });

        colorPentagon.on('mouseout touchstart', function() {
                   yoda.remove();
                   layer.draw();
         });
```

At the beginning you want:

```
   var imageObj = new Image();
   var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
       x: 0,
       y: 0,
       image: imageObj,
       width: 106,
       height: 118
   });
   imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg';
```

Comment: and yes, you would have to keep track of the which rectangle has which image by storing them in an array or some such thing, such as utilizing some complex ajax functionality which would retrieve an array of images for you.